# Error "No module named 'x'" but it is installed

Tags: python, libraries, modulenotfounderror

I've installed the library "tabulate" for a project I'm working on and it was working fine. I stopped and created a copy to have a backup with my functioning code but when I tried to run the copy the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate'" appeared. I closed everything and restarted my machine because one time that worked, but now when I open my project the error still appears. Then I decided to work on another part of the project which only uses library xlsxwriter (which I had just installed and also was working fine before), but the same thing happened, it showed the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'" when I tried to run it.

Can anyone help me figure out why this happens and how to solve it?

I've tried closing any other windows and shells of python, uninstalling and re installing the libraries and restarting my computer but nothing works.

Maybe it is important to mention that I am working in the python IDLE (3.11)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the libraries using `python -m pip install nameoflibrary`

Answer (score 0):

We need to come back to previous folder by typing 'cd' in terminal and execute again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).